# Cannot get the result form WebService Flex 4.6

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am newbie to the FLEX, and I have trouble on getting the result form my webservice.

In my project, I use the php function to form a webservice and return a checksum. The following form item can return the checksum normally.

```
<s:FormItem label="LoginCheck">
  <s:TextInput id="loginChecklastresult" text="{loginCheckResult.lastResult as int}"/>
</s:FormItem>
```

but, when I use the following code in the script.

```
protected function loginButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  loginCheckResult.token = accountloginService.loginCheck(usernameLogin.text,passworkLogin.text) ;
  var check:int = loginCheckResult.lastResult as int;
}
```

the value of "check" is always 0.

The respective call responser and the service are

```
<s:CallResponder id="loginCheckResult" />
<accountloginservice:AccountloginService id="accountloginService"
   fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
   showBusyCursor="true"
   />
```

and nothing fault is shown.